# C++ how to declare a temporary unnamed, uninitialized array?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

So I was writing a function which shall act like one, returning an array (as you know arrays are not allowed to be returned in C++) and for that I need one temporary unnamed which shall be used as default parameter value assigned to the last argument implicitly, like this:

```
template<size_t szArr, typename typeArrs>
auto fnAdd2ArrayElements(const typeArrs (&arr_0)[szArr], const typeArrs (&arr_1)[szArr], typeArrs (&&result)[szArr] = {}) -> typeArrs (&&)[szArr]
{
    for(size_t i(0); i < szArr; ++i)
        result[i] = arr_0[i] + arr_1[i];

    return move(result);
}
```

As you can see the 'result' parameter have a default parameter value an unnamed array which however will be always 'zero-filled', because of the empty brackets. This will decrease performance because as you can see my function doesn't cares of it's contents and will fill it all. Is there anyway I can declare it uninitialized. Something like this:

```
template<typename T, size_t sz> using identity = T [sz];

template<size_t szArr, typename typeArrs>
auto fnAdd2ArrayElements(const typeArrs (&arr_0)[szArr], const typeArrs (&arr_1)[szArr], typeArrs (&&result)[szArr] = identity<typeArrs, szArr> ()) -> typeArrs (&&)[szArr]
{
    for(size_t i(0); i < szArr; ++i)
        result[i] = arr_0[i] + arr_1[i];

    return move(result);
}
```

But the above code won't compile. So any ideas how this can be done?

EDIT: It seems another problems appear. Since we are returning an 'xvalue' (and not an 'prvalue'), if we store the result in an 'rvalue' reference, the life-time of the unnamed temporary wouldn't extends as if we have returned an array by value. Here is an example:

```
const int iArr[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};

const int iArr1[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};

int (&&added)[5]  = fnAdd2ArrayElements(iArr, iArr1); //this will create an dangling reference

added[0]; //illegal - accessing dangling reference
```

Comment: Why do you (think you) need to return an array? How do you plan on using this? [And why don't you use vector?]

Comment: Have you considered `std::array` ?

Comment: Yes but I want to directly use the built-in arrays.

Comment: Consider what happens when someone calls your function. A temporary is created for your `result` parameter. The function is called. The function returns a reference to the passed-in `result` parameter. The caller regains control and destroys the temporary.

Comment: Have you read the standard papers? Temporaries passed as a function arguments have life-time, equal to the expression which calls it. So if this expression uses the return value in some way - it would be useful.

Comment: Because as you can see my function initialize it. Why do we waste program time to zero-fill it?

Comment: Thanks but I already knew that. I hoped for a solution without using structures.

Comment: @Jako Yes, but that means the only way this function is useful is if you *immediately* use the result, prior to the destruction of the temporary. Something like `auto && added = fnAdd2ArrayElements(array1, array2);`, which seems like a perfectly valid use of the function, would be very dangerous.

Comment: The same construct can be used for every return value. And every return value will have the same life-time as the expression, where it's function was called.

Comment: So nobody will write something like this.

Comment: Heh. One very common idea in computing that I wholly support is to make things so easy even a complete idiot can use them. Your function needs a skilled person to understand how to use it, or at least how to use it safely. If you're okay with that, then that's fine. I personally wouldn't be, but it's a matter of opinion, so there's no point in arguing over that. :)

Comment: I'm on the same opinion but since 'C++' is a very complex language I want to make full use of it. Because even if you write something simple the same complex rules apply.

Comment: Using arrays with template arguments like this is not the greatest idea. It will stamp out a different function for every size array you pass into it.

Comment: Looks like you want to skip initialization that would be override by your function to me, return by value a `std::array` or an `UninitializedArray` seen in @Jarod42 answer is the proper way, and let the compiler do RVO for you. A line like this : `auto summed = Sum(array1, array2);` is easy to read, and does not involve temporary copy, Sum will directly write in summed thanks to copy elision.

Comment: So, you added a problem.  Yes, that is a problem with your design.  How do you want to use your function?  There are extremely limited contexts in which using your original design (without zero initialization) does something reasonable, but they are exceedingly narrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be risky since the lifetime of this temporary is **short**:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
struct UninitializedArray
{
    UninitializedArray() {}
    T arr[N];
};

template <size_t szArr, typename typeArrs>
typeArrs (&&)[szArr]
fnAdd2ArrayElements(
    const typeArrs (&arr_0)[szArr],
    const typeArrs (&arr_1)[szArr],
    typeArrs (&&result)[szArr] = UninitializedArray<typeArrs, szArr>{}.arr)
{
    std::cout << result[0] << std::endl; // To check that value is not initialized.

    for (size_t i(0); i < szArr; ++i) {
        result[i] = arr_0[i] + arr_1[i];
    }
    return std::move(result);
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dbad5184b0855b3f)

Comment: It is not short but exactly equal to the expression in which is used (in case where the function is called).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a good way to do this as you can't return an array as you correctly indicate.

An alternative approach would be to overload the function and within that overload, call the other function with the array parameter appropriately defined. (That's the only approach available to Java by the way).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that passing pointers to a function makes the function arguments decay to pointers (even if your code call them references, they are pointers). You can't return a pointer "into an array" - that would essentially mean that the compiler would have to do `memcpy(dest, fnAdd2ArrayElements(...), number_of_bytes);`, but it doesn't know the actual length of the `number_of_bytes` from the code.

Your code that you have already use three array arguments, so you could simply make the function into

```
void fnAdd2ArrayElements(const typeArrs (&arr_0)[szArr], 
                         const typeArrs (&arr_1)[szArr], 
                         typeArrs (&result)[szArr]);
```

You will, however, have to initialize the original `result`.

Alternatively, and this is my preferred solution: use `std::vector` [or similar].

Comment: No If a use a default parameter - a unnamed temporary.

Comment: Right, so the COMPILER will fill in an argument, you just don't have to TYPE it. Which means that it's created and passed to the function [obviously subject to optimisation, but you are using `result` in the loop, so the compiler can't remove the construction & destruction, at the very least]. C and C++ was never designed to do what you are trying to do, and I can't see any way that it will actually work.

Comment: It does - it compiles fine. And actually how do you think return values are created if not the same way as arguments? There is nothing magical with them, memory is allocated for them in the stack, the same as this function allocates it for the unnamed variable.